# Associate file types with my application C#

Tags: c#, registry, associations

I have been trying to get my application to associate certain file types with the app.
The easiest way as I have seen is to change the registry in [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT].
However, in windows 7 (and i'm guessing up) there is no way to do so **without** getting admin permission.
I have been tangling this issue for a very long time and I would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.
Which values do I need  to create and change in the registry? To what values? (My software name? What description?)

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
For that I created a faulty file type and associated it to my program.
Then I searched the registry for changes and copied the pathes of those changes.

The code is here and I would like to here if anyone has a better answer.

```
`
        public static void SetAssociation(string Extension, string KeyName, string OpenWith, string FileDescription)
        {
            RegistryKey OpenMethod;
            RegistryKey FileExts;
```

`//HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.avi\UserChoice -->"Progid" "Applications\YEPlayer.exe"
        OpenMethod = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Applications\", true);
        OpenMethod.CreateSubKey(KeyName + @".exe\shell\open\command").SetValue("",'"'+OpenWith+'"'+ " "+ '"'+"%1"+'"');

        FileExts = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\", true);
        foreach (string child in FileExts.OpenSubKey(Extension).GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            FileExts.OpenSubKey(Extension,true).DeleteSubKey(child);
        }
        FileExts.CreateSubKey(Extension + @"\UserChoice").SetValue("Progid", @"Applications\" + KeyName +".exe");
    }`

'

Thanks alot!

Comment: How to undo it?

Answer (score 0):

Just an example below of association between .txt files and TxtEditor.exe

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.txt] @="test.txt"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt] @="Text Document"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\DefaultIcon]
>   @="%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\imageres.dll,-102"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\shell\open]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\shell\open\command]
>   @="\"C:\TxtEditor.exe\" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\shell\print]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test.txt\shell\print\command]
>   @="\"C:\TxtEditor.exe\" /p \"%1\""

Also have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17023/System-File-Association

Comment: The problem I have i that I cant programmatically change HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. <br>How can I avoid it?